# Location map on logged on user

Tags: windows

Do you any application that will able to assist IT administrator its user location on a building based on the machine they logged (ie user logged on the particular machine, when logged and contact details)

Comment: Shopping requests like this are off topic and this will likely be closed.  Rewording may help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build such a solution for yourself, you can manually build a list of computer's locations, and insert a script in your login process that writes the user name and computer name to a centrally located file. Then parse the file to extract the latest logon for each user, and map users to locations using your list of computer's locations. That will give you a list of their locations in whatever format you want.. :)

Comment: Any suggestion on extracting information into webbased?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? You want to set up a webpage that displays the locations of your users? Have you considered the privacy implications of this?
Disregarding that, if you have a textfile list of locations + a textfile list of users + computers, then building a webpage that reads information from the text files will be trivial, which you can probably build using PHP. :)

Comment: Hi,This is for the sole purposed usage for intranet.